# What Shopify app runs on sl-promoserver.herokuapp.com

Tags: analytics

I was just going over some configuration on the Shopify store when I ran into this

```
<img src='https://sl-promoserver.herokuapp.com/conversion?order={{order_number}}&shop_domain={{shop.permanent_domain}}&subtotal_price={{subtotal_price}}&total_price={{total_price}}&code={{discounts.first.code}}&line_items={% for item in line_items %}{{item.quantity}},{% endfor %}' width='1' height='1'></img>
```

It sits in Additional Content & Scripts box in Checkout configuration. It's some kind of analytics service but I don't think that it's either sumAll or MarketBrain that I'm using. Definitely should've commented this.

Does anyone know what runs on sl-promoserver.herokuapp.com? The name makes me wonder if this was to be just a temporary mechanism for collecting data. I wonder if it does indeed belong to sumAll or MarketBrain.

Comment: Is this in your site you manage? If so then this is the wrong site for your question.

Comment: well, it's a Shopify analytics app. I'm merely trying to figure out which one. Seems to me like a general enough question.

Comment: Ah - in that case it may be on topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more searching around I'm quite certain that this belongs to ShopLogic - Promotions shopify app (they seemed to have renamed the app to Promoto). The app URL definitely fits.